# Sharing a log class in my program

Tags: c#, logging

I am going to use reflection to load some classes into my program at runtime. I wish for these classes to be able to use the same logging class as the main program.

Thinking ahead, how would I handle this? Would using a static class work?

I'd rather not use a logging framework as it is overkill for what I would like.

Thanks.

Comment: I do think the [`Trace` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) could come in handy.

Comment: Static class would certainly work as long as you do not multi-thread, or have multi-threading aware code. Note that in order to use your custom logger in the dynamically loaded parts you will have to have a reference to your custom logging class or interface (in terms of metadata) so in practice all your dynamic dlls will have to reference your main module with the logger class/interface anyway. May be using a logging framework is not an overkill after all.

Comment: I don't see what's "overkill" about using a very lightweight and easy-to-use framework like log4net, which would allow you to set something like this up in about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want to use a logging framework (which can be understandable) then you might want to look at the Singleton pattern.

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Notice how this class can only be created/accessed/reached from its `.Instance` attribute, which all shares the *same* instance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at log4net. That will handle all the things you want. And if you need to log somewhere special, implement your own appender to do so. Other logging frameworks will provide the functions you need. No need to reinvent logging.

[log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with singleton note that in C# it can be implemented in less verbose way:

```
public class Singletone
{
   public static readonly Singletone Instance = new Singletone();

   private Singletone() {}
   // other methods 
   public void DoTheJob(){}
}

// usage
Singletone.Instance.DoTheJob();
```

This implementation resolves issues like lazy initialization (field initializers are executed only when class is used the first time in the app domain) as well as thread safety (static initializers are guaranteed to be thread safe in .NET).

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your logger implementation with a common interface named ILogger - all the classes that you will load will accept the interface in their constructor - and you can Inject your logger implementation into them when creating them.
Also - about the loading at runtime - have you heard of MEF? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx - it might be of help to you in that regard,and will automatically inject the logger dependency into the new classes you load

I don't think a singleton logger referenced by the classes is good since it will tightly couple the logger from your codebase to the classes you make. injecting and interface in the constructor will loosely couple them from the logger,and make them more independent & testable.